# PHP cURL - authorization token missing

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to cURL apptweak (ref - https://apptweak.io/api )

```
curl -H 'X-Apptweak-Key: your-api-key' https://api.apptweak.com/ios/applications/284882215.json
```

I have my key and can curl from the terminal. In PHP, I get "authorization token missing".

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.apptweak.com/ios/applications/284882215.json&country=US&language=en',
    CURLOPT_POST => 1,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array(

   X-Apptweak-Key => 'MY-KEY-IS-HERE'
    )
));
$resp = curl_exec($curl);

print $resp;
curl_close($curl);
```

Is X-Apptweak-Key => 'MY-KEY-IS-HERE' being a POST field the issue here?

What is wrong?

Comment: You need to set it as a header, not as a post field.

Comment: **'X-Apptweak-Key: your-api-key'** pass it in your header.

Comment: Still getting the error of missing token - updated code to add key to header - https://pastebin.com/V488XmLT Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

you can add X-Apptweak-Key between single quotes it's a key

```
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array(
   'X-Apptweak-Key' => 'MY-KEY-IS-HERE'
    )
```

or you can try this:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8',
        'Authorization: Basic MY-KEY-IS-HERE'));
```

or you can use:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "X-Apptweak-Key:MY-KEY-IS-HERE");
```

Comment: Tried that - Authorization token missing

Comment: @adbanoub Makram Still getting the error of missing token - updated code - https://pastebin.com/V488XmLT